# Use C# RegEx to retrieve a list of matching strings found in a source string?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm a RegEx novice, so I'm hoping someone out there can give me a hint.

I want to find a straightforward way (using RegEx?) to extract a list/array of values that match a pattern from a string.

If source string is "Hello @bob and @mark and @dave", I want to retrieve a list containing "@bob", "@mark" and "@dave" or, even better, "bob", "mark" and "dave" (without the @ symbol).

So far, I have something like this (in C#):

```
string note = "Hello, @bob and @mark and @dave";
var r = new Regex(@"/(@)\w+/g");
var listOfFound = r.Match(note);
```

I'm hoping listOfFound will be an array or a List containing the three values.

I could do this with some clever string parsing, but it seems like this should be a piece of cake for RegEx, if I could only come up with the right pattern.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don't write a regular expression in C# using `/` and `/g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexes in C# don't need delimiters and options must be supplied as the second argument to the constructor, but are not required in this case as you can get all your matches using [`Regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8). Note that by using a `lookbehind` for the `@` (`(?<=@)`) we can avoid having the `@` in the match:

```
string note = "Hello, @bob and @mark and @dave";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=@)\w+");
foreach (Match match in r.Matches(note))
    Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", match.Value, match.Index);
```

Output:

```
Found 'bob' at position 8
Found 'mark' at position 17
Found 'dave' at position 27
```

To get all the values into a list/array you could use something like:

```
string note = "Hello, @bob and @mark and @dave";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=@)\w+");
// list of matches
List<String> Matches = new List<String>();
foreach (Match match in r.Matches(note))
    Matches.Add(match.Value);
// array of matches
String[] listOfFound = Matches.ToArray();
```

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without Regex, for example:

```
var listOfFound = note.Split().Where(word => word.StartsWith("@"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
var listOfFound = r.Match(note);
```

by

```
var listOfFound = r.Matches(note);
```